# How Format Vertical Data Label in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a chart and the Vertical Data Labels. 
They are 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 etc. 
How do I remove 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Right click the axis, `format axis`; under `axis options` change the `major units` to something like `fixed` `1.0`